# Get scale of instancemesh in vertexshader

Tags: javascript, matrix, three.js

I'm using Object3D to set scale.x/y/z for my instance mesh (the geometry is a unit box).

What's the proper way to access that in the vertex shader?

Is that instanceMatrix? (though that seems to be a 4x4 matrix). If so, how do I access it?

Comment: The easy way : use a scale attribute. Or you'll have to decompose instanceMatrix in your shader

Comment: `vec3 scale = vec3(instanceMatrix[0][0], instanceMatrix[1][1], instanceMatrix[2][2]);`?

Comment: @prisoner849 that worked for me until i applied rotation to the instance. doesn't seem to work if the object is rotated. ended up doing soju's suggestion and just added new attribute.